# Do you know what protocol is this?

Tags: video, network-protocols, dvr

I have a H.264 standalone DVR from Hexacctv that streams 4 channels from its cameras. I use SkyVizor NVClient to get streaming video from channels. But I need to be authenticated by the the StandAlone DVR.

Now I need to write my own program to get video from this device. I need to know the protocol of this device. I tried to use WireShark to find out what protocol is used. When the client wants to authenticate user sends these bytes to server:

```
0000000: 2823 0000 0000 0000 6164 6d69 6e00 0000  (#......admin...
0000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 3531 3930 3730 0000  ........519070..
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 7e2f 68c4 80e5 742f  ........~/h...t/
0000050: 68c4 80e5 14da e9a9 fc56 0050 56c0 0001  h........V.PV...
0000060: 0050 56c0 0008 0000 0000 0000            .PV.........
```

**admin** is user name and **519070** is password.

Does someone know what this protocol is? The default port is 8200 and I think every client request starts with `(#`.

**Edit : I can use HiDvrOcx to watch channels**.

Comment: The plaintext dump is not very useful, since *all* bytes over 0x7f are shown as dots. Wireshark can show it in various better forms.

Comment: @grawity~> Thank you for you comment. I added the c like array too.

Answer (score 0):

From the basic google search found this TCP 8200 GoToMyPC (unofficial) and also listen TRIVNET application.

You can use the below reference guide.

[Link](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8200)